# trouble in updating multiple rows in mysql db

Tags: php, sql-update

can someone tell me were I wrote wrong ? this code shows data from database but when I press submit it just reload the page and none of those field's update in database ...
shall I change variables in update query to  for example : $_POST['name']

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="username"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="db"; // Database name
$tbl_name="test"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>mid</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id[]=$rows['id']; 
 ?>

<tr>
<td align="center">
<input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<? echo $rows['lastname']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="midmark[]" type="text" id="midmark" value="<? echo $rows['midmark']; ?>">
</td>
</tr>
<?
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                $sql1=mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', midmark='$midmark[$i]'  WHERE id='$id[$i]' ");
                $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
                }
            }

                if(isset($result1)){
                header("location:multiple.php");
                }
                mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: adding the index to the inputs makes it easier to update ie name="id[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]"

Comment: its `isset($_POST['submit'])` it should be `isset($_POST['Submit'])` Next what is $name here?

Comment: Believe you never set the variables in your query. Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: $name is the name of that person its not username

Comment: I have changed the code to this : 

    <?php
       if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql1=mysql_query("UPDATE '.$tbl_name.' SET name=\''$name[$i]', lastname=\''$lastname[$i]', midmark=\''$midmark[$i]'  WHERE id=\''$id[$i]' ");
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
        }
       }
              
        if(isset($result1)){
        header("location:multiple.php");
        }
        mysql_close();
           
    ?>

but it's not working i meand it do not update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope it'll help you.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $sql1=mysql_query("UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET name='".magic($_REQUEST['name'][$i])."', lastname='".magic($_REQUEST['lastname'][$i])."', midmark='".magic($_REQUEST['midmark'][$i])."'  WHERE id='".magic($_REQUEST['id'][$i])."' ");
            $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
     }
}


function magic($value)
{
   if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
       $value = stripslashes( $value );
   if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
       $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
   else
       $value = addslashes( $value );
   return $value;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked. is this code safe or i should change it ? for sql injection ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a '.' between the variables in your SQL string and the text and using single quotes - it may be trying to evaluate both parts of $name[$i] 
, e.g.

```
 'UPDATE '.$tbl_name.' SET name=\''.$name[$i].'    ...etc
```

Also, always echo the SQL string before the query when testing to see what it will do

Answer (score 0):

display and input using:-

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
<input name="data[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>][name]" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="data[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>][lastname]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<? echo $rows['lastname']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="data[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>][midmark]" type="text" id="midmark" value="<? echo $rows['midmark']; ?>">
</td>
</tr>
```

then process using:-

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            while(list($index,$record)=each($_POST['data']))
            {
                $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='".mysql_real_escape_string($record['name'])."', lastname='".mysql_real_escape_string($record['lastname'])."', midmark='".mysql_real_escape_string($record['nmidmarkame'])."  WHERE id=".intval($index));
                $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post variables are set wrong.

first of all your if statements, post['submit'] is lowercase, it needs to be the same as in the form:

```
isset($_POST['Submit'])
```

Then you need to read the rest of the post values and store them in variables or at least reference them properly:

```
$sql1=mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', midmark='$midmark[$i]'  WHERE id='$id[$i]' ");
```

Should become:

```
$name = $_POST['name[$i]'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname[$i]'];

$sql1=mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname',  ...
```